# How to install additional gems with bundler in production environment?

Tags: ruby, bundler, production-environment

I have a staging server. And I've got some issue I'd like to investigate right there. But I forgot to add `byebug` to `Gemfile`. I can surely add it locally, run `bundle`, commit to repository, deploy. But isn't there an easier way?

When I try to change `Gemfile` remotely and run `bundle` I get:

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the /home/gccs/website-backend/releases/20161018143057/Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* byebug
```

Gems are installed with `capistrano`, basically, like so:

```
bundle install --path /home/user/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `.bundle/config` changing `BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'` to `'0'` (or removing it) is enough in order to be allowed by Bundler to manage gems in a deployment environment. Then you can edit the `Gemfile`, run `bundle`, restart your application and the custom gems are ready to be used.

If you intend to use them outside of the application runtime (f.e. if you need  `pry` in `rails console`) restarting the server is not needed.

Comment: I added more info to the question. And I can say, `bundler` produces the same error message with `Gemfile.local`.

Comment: You need to edit `.bundle/config` and remove this line: `BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'`. This is starting becoming more complex than commit, push and deploy ;)

Comment: `You need to edit .bundle/config and remove this line: BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'` Or just change it to '0'. Anyways, great, it works, thanks. `This is starting becoming more complex than commit, push and deploy` Um, not at all, you just need to "unfreeze" changing `Gemfile`, change `Gemfile`, and run `bundle`. No need for `Gemfile.local`. Consider updating your answer, please.

Comment: Not sure if it was the right thing to do, but I decided to create my own answer. What I don't like in yours is that it has nonrelevant details (`Gemfile.local`). Well, if it were only that, I wouldn't probably care. But it starts with them, almost puts a stress on them. If you drop the `Gemfile.local` part, or at least move it to the end, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, actually removing `BUNDLE_FROZEN` is enough. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're unable to install additional gems is because the bundle is frozen. You can check it like so:

```
$ grep FROZEN .bundle/config
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
```

If you remove the line (as suggested by [mdesantis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110991/52499)) or change "1" to "0", you'll be able to install whatever gems you like, as if it were developer machine. But generally it's best to restore the value, if no more needed. Not sure if `bundler` will do that automatically on next deploy.